# XML parsing by tag-names and attributes method in DOM tree structure

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse this xml file but I'm only getting the root elements and not it's child nodes.
I need information of some specific values from the nodes like using .item() method. Since,  I'm not entering it's child nodes so it didn't give me the specified values. Please help me solving this...

XML file

```
<Ws>
    <Id V='862631039910699'>
        <Dt V='08/07/22;11/25'>
            <T V='24.3;24.3;24.3'/>
            <H V='98.0;98.0;98.0'/>
            <W V='1.3;272'/>
            <G V='25;2.4'/>
            <A V='0.00;468;472;471'/>
            <D V='0.00;8.9;8.065;0.0000;0.0000'/>
        </Dt>
    </Id>
</Ws>
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: I posted the code in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

```
package api;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;
public class Web{
    public static void main(String argv[])
    {
        try {
            
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Prakhar\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\WBE2.xml.txt");

            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

            
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(file);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            System.out.println("Root element: " + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
            
            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Ws");

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); ++i) {
                Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                System.out.println("\nNode Name :" + node.getNodeName());
                
                if (node.getNodeType()== Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                   
                    Element tElement = (Element)node;
                    

                    System.out.println("IMEI: " +
                            doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("V").getNodeValue());

                    System.out.println("Date/Time: " +
                            doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("V").getNodeValue());

                    System.out.println("Temperature: " +
                            doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(2).getAttributes().getNamedItem("V").getNodeValue());
                    
                    System.out.println("Humidity: " +
                            doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(1).getAttributes().getNamedItem("V").getNodeValue());
                    
                    System.out.println("Wind Speed: " +
                            doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getFirstChild().getChildNodes().item(2).getAttributes().getNamedItem("V").getNodeValue());



                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).